# Error multipling float and int with F#

Tags: types, f#, variable-assignment

I have defined the following record:

```
type Ball =
    {
       center : Vector3<m> 
       radius : float32<m>
       color : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color 
    }
```

I'm trying to create a list of Ball this way:

```
let BallRadius = 0.2<m>
let list =
    [ for i in 0 .. 9 ->
        {
            center = { X = BallRadius + (float i) * BallRadius * 2.0 ; Y = 0.0<m>; Z = 0.0<m>}; //1 error
            radius = BallRadius; //1 error
            color = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.White
        }

    ]
```

Seems that in the first case i is an int and I can't multiply if for float. In the second case I can't assign a float to a float32. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can't multiple floats by ints, so you'll need `center = BallRadius + (float i) * BallRadius * 2.0`
2. `radius = (float32 BallRadius) * 1.0f<m>` works, though I'm not sure it's the most idiomatic.

That aside, it's not clear to me how adding two `BallRadius` gets you a `Vector3<m>`, unless your vector is just a float...

Comment: Your solution works, but it's quite boring playing all this conversion for every assignment, isn't it? On the other hand using measure is very useful, isn't there any clean solution to make this kind of assignment without always perform some kind of cast?

Comment: Well, using the same types might help, but I'm not sure if that option is available to you. Can you change the definition of radius in Ball?

Comment: Actually I should keep the measure unit. I'm developping a little game and measures are very useful in order to verify at compile time several operations.

Comment: @Heisenbug: note that `0.2` means float64, you should use float32 literals like `0.2f` instead. Unless double precision maths is absolutely needed of course.

Comment: @Stringer: I can't use 0.2f. It gives me an error complaining about the measure unit.

Comment: @Heisenbug: Really? I thought float32 and decimal types support units-of-measure too.

Comment: @Stringer: I don't know . I'm a F# newbie and I still don't know the language. Can you post the code you are thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

```
[<Measure>] type m

type Vector3<[<Measure>] 'a> =
  {
    X : float32<'a>
    Y : float32<'a>
    Z : float32<'a>
  }

type Ball =
  {
    center : Vector3<m>;
    radius : float32<m>;
  }

let BallRadius = 0.2f<m>
let list = [ for i in 0..9 ->  { center = { X = BallRadius + (float32 i) * BallRadius * 2.0f; Y = 0.0f<m>; Z = 0.0f<m>}; radius = BallRadius;} ]
```

Here's what works for me.